# Wha't is the meaning of global option in dig command and how to use them?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, dig

```
 dig mt-example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.4.1-P1 <<>> mt-example.com
;; global options:  printcmd
```

I wonder what's the global options and what

```
printcmd
```

meaning, I searched in internet but still don't know what is printcmd

Answer (score 1):

`dig` takes options, say:

> +[no]trace  Toggle tracing of the delegation path from the root name servers for the name being looked up.

You can have many queries in the command line, and each one takes its options.

```
dig query opts query opts
```

If you want one option to apply to all queries, you add it at the beginning and it becomes *global*.

```
dig +trace query
```

`printcmd` ... that belongs to a pretty old version. It is currently `cmd`.

Check the `dig` manpage in your system for `printcmd` and other options you might have. For the more up to date `dig` you can [read this manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dnsutils/dig.1.en.html).